# Serializer.is_valid() returns False all the time. Serializer.errors is empty

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send some images through POSTMAN to my API.
However, all the time I am getting `206 status`, which is returned if `serializer.is_valid()` is not `True`. Moreover, `serializer.errors` is empty for every request.
It was working fine before I have added images field. `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` fields are already created.

It works well using admin page of Django.

I am sending a request using POSTMAN.
The response I am getting:

```
{
    "data": {}
}
```

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

Models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True,
    db_index=True,
    editable=False,
    default=uuid4,
)
city = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    verbose_name = (u'City'),
    default="NY",
)
description=models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    verbose_name=(u'desc'),
    default="Офигенная хата",
)
price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    default=0,
    verbose_name=(u'Price')
)
requirements = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    verbose_name = (u'Req'),
    default="Clean"
)
address = models.CharField(
    max_length=50,
    verbose_name = (Address'),
    default="Wall st"
)
roommates_needed= models.PositiveIntegerField(
    verbose_name=(u''),
    default=None
)
images = models.FileField(
    upload_to = 'pic_folder/%Y/%m/%d/',
    default = 'pic_folder/None/no-img.jpg',
    verbose_name = (img'),
    blank = True,
)
gender_choices=(
    (1, u'Lady'),
    (2, u'Boy'),
    (3, u'anyone')
)
roommate_gender = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    choices=gender_choices,
    default=3,
    verbose_name=(u'gender '),)
status_choices = (
    (1, u'Active'),
    (2, u'Not active'),
    (3, u'Blocked'),
)
status = models.PositiveIntegerField(
    default=1,
    choices=status_choices,
    verbose_name=(u'Status'))
owner = models.OneToOneField(
    'User',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    verbose_name=(u'Owner'),)
def __str__(self):
    return self.owner.name
class Meta:
    verbose_name = (order')
    verbose_name_plural = (u'3. Order list')
```

serializer.py

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = OrderPostSerializer(data=request.data.copy(), partial=True)
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    ## Проверяем совпадает ли токен передаваемый пользователем с тем что в настройках, авторизован он или нет.
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        token = request.META.get('HTTP_TOKEN', '')
        if token != settings.MAINMODULE_TOKEN:
            return Response({'detail': 'unauthorized'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    if serializer.is_valid() in request.data:
        serializer.save()
        perform_create()
        return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response({'data': serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_206_PARTIAL_CONTENT)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(content_object=self.request.user, image=self.request.FILES.get('images'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the serializer is not invalid. This test:

```
if serializer.is_valid() in request.data:
```

checks that True (or False) is in the request data, which it won't be. Remove that `in`:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
```

(Also, note that your queryset and parser_classes variables are not used. It looks like you've copied those from a class-based view, you don't need them in this function view.)

Comment: Thank you, now it works. I have that kind of check, if serializer.is_valid() in request.data, in every other serializer. However, they are working well, so what is wrong with this one?

Comment: Well maybe some of your other requests *do* contain True or False as a key, although I can't think why they would. But why would you use this code in the first place? You need to write code intentionally. Write code that means what you intend it to mean.